# Problem with text formating in applescript

Tags: applescript, text-manipulation

I have been trying to tackle a problem I am having extracting text from a website and filtering it to get the information I want. I have gotten to the point where I create a TextEdit file from the website that looks like this:

```
7:00
Name of Meeting: Location Bad
Address
Area
8:00
Name of Meeting: Location Good
Address
Area
Noon
Name of Meeting: Location Good 2
Address
Area
3:00 pm
Name of Meeting: Location Bad 2
Area
```

My goal is to extract all meetings at certain locations (Location Good and Location Good 2). Ideally filtering just this information --> Time @ Location Good, Time @ Location Good 2.

I do not know how to format the text in order to get this done. I have tried filtering it, but since information is all separated on different lines, the filter comes back as just the keyword I am filtering (using Automator). To work around this, I've just done it manually and set an applescript to send me a text message with the information I already hand-filtered. This works for now, but when information on the website changes, my information will be out of date.

Here is the website: 
https://loukyaa.org/meetings/?tsml-day=6&tsml-region=louisville

Question is: how do I manipulate the text in order to filter the information that I want? I am interested in filtering all meetings for "Icehouse" and "Token 3 Club." Thank you!

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question, but I can have a guess at what it is.  But for anyone to have a chance to offer any help, you need to show us exactly what you're dealing with.  Ideally, a URL to the website where you're extracting the text from will get you the best help.  If not, then you need to format the text in your question so that it exactly mirrors what you're handling at your end.  Otherwise, code someone writes to parse text displaying one way on our machine isn't going to work particularly well when the text is formatted differently on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the incomplete information presented in your question, let me offer a solution for both **Safari** and **Google Chrome** to open the *target* **URL** in a *new window*, use **JavaScript** to get the *inner text* to the *table of meetings*, close the *window*, and filter it to the form of **Time @ Location**, e.g. **7:00 am @ Token 3 Club** containing the meeting *time* and *location* for **Icehouse** and **Token 3 Club**.

Using **JavaScript**, in this use case, it returns *paragraphs of tab delimitated text* in the *variable* `foo` which will be filtered using `awk` in a `do shell script` *command*, where the final output is stored in a *variable* named `bar`, which you can then do *whatever* you'd like with.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is for **Safari**:

```
set theURL to "https://loukyaa.org/meetings/?tsml-day=6&tsml-region=louisville"

tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists ¬
        (buttons of UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            application process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    set foo to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.getElementById('meetings_tbody').innerText;" in document 1
    close its front window
end tell

set awkCommand to ¬
    "awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\t\"; OFS=\" @ \"}/Icehouse|Token 3 Club/{print $1,$3}'"

set bar to do shell script awkCommand & " <<< " & foo's quoted form
```

- **NOTE:** This *code* was tested under **macOS High Sierra**, however, for **macOS Mojave** and later, remove the *words* `buttons of` from the `repeat until exists ¬ ...` *code*.
- **NOTE:** `do JavaScript` only works *if* **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** is checked on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu, which is hidden by default and can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced**

---

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is for **Google Chrome**:

```
set theURL to "https://loukyaa.org/meetings/?tsml-day=6&tsml-region=louisville"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    set URL of active tab of (make new window) to theURL
    repeat until (loading of tab 1 of window 1 is false)
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell active tab of front window to set foo to ¬
        execute javascript ¬
            "document.getElementById('meetings_tbody').innerText;"
    close its front window
end tell

set awkCommand to ¬
    "awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\t\"; OFS=\" @ \"}/Icehouse|Token 3 Club/{print $1,$3}'"

set bar to do shell script awkCommand & " <<< " & foo's quoted form
```

**NOTE:** This should work *by default*, as **Google Chrome** allows execution of **JavaScript**.

---

In either case the *variable* `bar` contains e.g.:

```
7:00 am @ Token 3 Club
8:00 am @ Token 3 Club
8:30 am @ Icehouse
8:30 am @ Icehouse
10:30 am @ Icehouse
2:00 pm @ Token 3 Club
4:00 pm @ Token 3 Club
6:00 pm @ Icehouse
6:00 pm @ Icehouse
6:00 pm @ Token 3 Club
8:00 pm @ Icehouse
8:00 pm @ Token 3 Club
10:30 pm @ Token 3 Club
```

You can then do with it as you wish.

Also note the `FS=\"\t\";` portion of the `awk` *command* will expand to a normal *tab* character when compiled in, e.g., **Script Editor**. The use of `\t` is necessary when posting *code* on this site, otherwise it will show as, e.g., `FS=\" \";` and then when copying the *code* it will not be a normal *tab* character once compiled.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thank you user3439894! I am now learning how to use awk command, as it is clearly very useful! This is exactly the text manipulation I was looking for! The Google Chrome works like a charm, however, not the Safari... it just keeps running until I stop it. I double checked the javascript permissions, and both my Safari and Chrome have it enabled.

Comment: @just_dabbling, All of the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ shown in my answer works for me as is on my system running **macOS High Sierra**, what version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Catalina. 10.15.3

Comment: @just_dabbling, I've now tested it in **macOS Mojave** and **macOS Catalina**, so with **Safari** for **macOS Mojave** and later, remove the _words_ `buttons of` from the `repeat until exists ¬ ...` _code_ and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

@user3439894's answer is excellent, and he's shown you some good, robust techniques for determining whether a webpage has loaded; some elementary JavaScript; and the power of `awk`.

I decided to do it a different way.  I use JavaScript to do all the heavy processing, largely because my ultimate goal was to obtain a list of `record` objects, each representing a single event listed on the webpage, from which I extracted the name, location and time of each event.

```
tell application id "com.apple.Safari" to tell ¬
    document 1 to set allEvents to do JavaScript ¬
    "Array.from(document
               .querySelectorAll('tbody#meetings_tbody '+
                                'tr '+
                                'td.name,'+
                                'td.time,'+
                                'td.location'))
               .reduce((ξ,x,i,L) => { 
                        ξ=Array.from(ξ);
                        i%3==1 && ξ.push({
                                'name': L[i].innerText,
                                'time': L[i-1].innerText,
                                'location': L[i+1].innerText
                        }); 
                        return ξ;
               });"
```

The variable `allEvents` should then contain something like this:

```
{{|name|:"Saturday @ 7", |time|:"7:00 am", location:"Token 3 Club"},
 {|name|:"Early Bird Meeting", |time|:"8:00 am", location:"Token 3 Club"},
 {|name|:"Saturday Morning Meditation Group", |time|:"8:30 am", location:"Christ Church United Methodist"},
 {|name|:"Saturday Morning Gratitude Group", |time|:"8:30 am", location:"Icehouse"},
 ...,
 {|name|:"Agape", |time|:"10:30 pm", location:"Token 3 Club"}}
```

I'm not sure how familiar you are with AppleScript `list` or `record` objects.  If you examine the contents carefully, you'll see that each event is represented by an object that looks like this:

```
{|name|:"...", |time|:"...", location:"..."}
```

That is a **`record`**, which contains three *`properties`*: `|name|`, `|time|`, and `location`.  Each `property` has a value, which you retrieve by referencing the **`<property> of <record>`**.  So, if one creates a record object and assigns it to a variable thus:

```
set R to {a:1, b:"two", c:pi}
```

then:

```
set myvar to b of R
```

will retrieve the value of property `b` belonging to record `R` and store it in the variable `myvar`.  So `myvar` will now evaluate to `"two"`.

`allEvents` isn't just one `record` object; it's many.  It's a `list` of them.  Here's an example of a list:

```
set L to {1, "two", pi, 2^2, "5.0"}
```

It **doesn't** contain properties; it only contains values, and these are termed `items`.  A `list` is held in strict order, whereas a `record` is not.  Therefore, the value `"two"` will **always** appear as the second `item` in that list, but in the record, it can appear at the beginning, middle, or end, but will always be attached to the property `b`.  To retrieve an item from a list:

```
set myvar to item 2 of L
```

So, skipping to the end somewhat, if you want the location of the 4th event in that list:

```
return the location of item 4 in allEvents --> "Icehouse"
```

You'll still want to follow @user3439894's example, and implement a test to determine when the page has loaded (unless you intend to trigger the script manually only after loading the page yourself).  @user3439894 has also shown you how to adapt the code to a Chromium-based browser (Google Chrome, Vivaldi, Brave).

Comment: My head just exploded. But thank you! I will give both a try and comb through and try to understand :)!

Comment: It wont let me upvote, but I found it incredibly helpful!